# custom fields not adding to Drupal views

Tags: custom-fields, drupal-views

I'm trying to build a drupal view and pull in rm custom data
For both contact (client) and case
(view for case contact, relationships include case contact id-case id, and case contact id- contact id)

From add fields- all the data sets I need are visible

After selecting fields and clicking add, I'm taken back to the views edit screen without the option to edit the field label etc. And the field does not appear in the field list.

This is not consistent... for example from data set "x"
fields, a, b c, d and e are all available to choose. Fields b and d, can be added to the view. Fields a,c and e fail to materialise.

Anyone seen anything like this? Anything else I should be looking at?

(Drupal 7.60, civi 5.3.1)

settings.php file has been updated

The views cache, drupal cache and civicrm cache have been cleared several times

One of the custom field sets in question
[image: Custom Field Set]

Selecting fields to include in view
[image: views interface]

Only 2 fields out of 7 end up in views table (end columns)
Other Details and Project

[image: table headers]

Comment: Are you sure settings.php is up to date? If so, try clearing Views cache, which is on Settings/Advanced in Views.

Comment: Updated settings.php

Civi, drupal and views cache cleared multiple times

Still no dice

Comment: Check the custom field is searchable?

Comment: @TonyHorrocks fields are set as searchable- see screengrabs added to post

Comment: happy to look over your shoulder on a screenshare (skype peter.davis59 / hangout  peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz etc) if you think it might help. seems a bit mysterious

Comment: @petednz-fuzion If you're free to do that it would be a great help. When would be the best time for you? I'm happy to log in late evening (9-10pm uk) if that's easiest?

Comment: anytime in next 12 or so hours

Comment: Sorry. Didn't log back in last night to check.  

I'm unavailable this evening (tomorrow morning for you?)

If I tried to reach you on Friday Morning (your time) would that be ok?

Comment: And none of the fields are inadvertently set to 'exclude from display' in the field set up of the view?

Comment: craig did you get a resolution - can you add your own answer perhaps so this question doesn't have zero accepted answers

Comment: I've not got anywhere near to fixing this.

I've asked a colleague to update drupal views related modules all to latest and then I'm going to try and re-build the view from scratch, but struggling to find time to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Civi to latest version.

Updated views related modules in Drupal to latest versions.

Rebuilt view.

Original view was based on case contact id, and pulled in case details and case contact details.

Rebuilt as a case view, and then added single relationship to Case Contact.

So either
1) upgrading modules
or
2) not building complicated queries in views in the first place

Worked.

Massive thanks to Pete from Fuzion for help and support.

And to everyone  else who chipped in

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is missing from your Drupal settings.php file. Here's where you get the information to add to it:

https://www.yourdomain.com/civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1

That will give you all the information that needs to be added. Each time you add custom fields/profiles to CiviCRM, it is a good idea to update that listing in your settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks Jenni, I had already done that. I've editted original post to make that more explicit.

Comment: Would you be able to give us a screenshot of the list of fields from the custom fields page? Maybe there is something specific about those fields that is causing it since you're getting access to some, but not all.

Comment: Hi Jenni, I've updated the ticket with screen grabs.

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Hmmm. Is there content in all those fields? Maybe you've got them set to hide if empty? If not, I think we've all mentioned about all the troubleshooting I can think of...

Comment: Thanks Jenni, I don't even get the dialog box to set  the hide if empty options. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Ah, it's inside Views when you click on the fields you're using. There's a list of options, including one that allows you to tell it what to do if it's empty.

Comment: I don't know if this relates, but you can see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/how-to-display-individual-custom-fields-in-a-participants-view for more explanations (not solutions)